# Php ob_get_contents() returns empty string if the included file during buffering is not small

Tags: php, codeigniter, output-buffering

Let's say i have a file consisting of 5 lines of text and every line has 50 chars. The output buffer contents are returned correctly but if I have a file containing 100 lines of text the output buffer returns empty string (string with value null).

I do it like so:

```
ob_start();
include "file.php"
$string = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

OR

```
$string = $this->load->view('view', $data, true);
```

Im doing this inside codeigniter if that makes any difference.

I tried to load the file with Code igniter's load->view function with third parameter set to true the result is the same. Tried also giving [ob_start()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) a big number -> ob_start(9999999); same result;

Comment: You should have called ob_start( "someCallback", 99999999 ); size is the second parameter

Comment: What's the content of the files that aren't working?

Answer (score 1):

I'd propose to use [ob_get_flush](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-flush.php) to ensure, that **nothing is still kept** in some internal buffer..

Quite unlikely, but what does this instead of your code print?

```
require_once( "file.php" );
```

Just to ensure, that the stuff in `file.php` isn't surrounded by `<?php /** **/ php?>`.

And what does

```
echo ob_get_level();
```

output just before your code? Shouldn't be relevant, if other outbut-buffering is already enabled, but...

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using ob functions to get the contents of a file? Why not file_get_contents?

Comment: `file_get_contents()` does not parse the PHP (which is assume there is some to be executed since the file is named file.php)

Comment: That's how I originally read it, but there is the possibility that the lines of text are outputted dynamically by PHP. Why, otherwise, would the file have a PHP extension?

Comment: Agreed. Wondered the same thing.

Comment: yes there is some php lines in there, but i tried with html only and the result was the same

Comment: if i dont use the buffering the file outputs just fine that is the strange thing but i dont rly want to output it i want to capture it in a string.

Comment: @AlexanderBeninski: What does the file output?

Answer (score 0):

you have just to add some lines in index.php (the root of CodeIgniter)

```
ob_start();
```

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * APPLICATION ENVIRONMENT
 *------------
+

```
require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';

$data = ob_get_contents();
ob_clean();
echo $data; /// or anything else
```

that's all !